# Are you able to run windows command from Blazor app?

Tags: cmd, blazor

Is it possible to run windows CMD commands from a Blazor app and output the command responses to the app?

Comment: Blazor webassembly or blazor server?

Comment: It's possible if you're running on a Windows server and you are willing to do some extra programming.  But don't.  Just don't.  If you really want a command line, log into your server.

Answer (score 2):

No, your in an "isolated" Browser window with no access to the host operating system. Consider the security implications of being able to do so.

Comment: Ahh, good point, thank you for the clear and concise answer!

Comment: @Darkmatter5 - if this answers your question please mark as an answer.  I don't care about the points - others will open it and think that it still needs answering ;-).

Comment: Also, you can use .net MAUI Blazor app but the result application will be a windows app. Not a web app